# Deploying Jupyter notebooks as a component in AI Platform pipelines

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, object-detection, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, kubeflow-pipelines

I have a Jupyter Notebook containing the model creation, model deployment on the AI Platform, and creating versions. I am able to get the predictions for my model. Now I am trying to build a CI/CD pipeline automating the entire process. Is there a way that I can pass in my entire Jupyter notebook as a component in AI Platform Pipelines?

Comment: I understand that you want to add your notebook as a step in your AI Platform Pipeline. Is it right?

Comment: Yes Esteves....that is correct...

Comment: Try to create a docker image using [papermill](https://papermill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill) to create a parameterized notebook, which can then be executed via CI/CD. This [article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/best-practices-that-can-improve-the-life-of-any-developer-using-jupyter-notebooks) explains a bit more in detail in the 'Reproducible Notebooks' section.